# Adding to existing ribbon in Outlook c#

Tags: c#, outlook, ribbon, ribbon-control

I would like to be able to add a button into the outlook ribbon, the idea is that when you access your calendar it would show in the "Home" ribbon. How would I go about doing this, ideas or links?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main trick in adding to an **existing** ribbon is that you have to create your own (new) ribbon but set the `ControlId` property (*ribbon designer properties*) or the `idMso` (*ribbon xml*) to `TabHome`. The ribbongroups on your ribbon will then be added to the existing Home ribbon.

A complete list of all other ribbon names can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3582)

Comment: Does this work for office 2010? I am setting a ribbontype to Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer and then setting ControlIdtype to Office and then OfficeID to TabHome (which then sets the ControlId to TabHome) - but it throws an error - Failed to find office control by id.